# Change tickmark labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a median monthly house price graph calculated using:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=duration, y=price)) + stat_summary(fun.y="median", geom="line")  + 
  ggtitle("Median monthly prices over time") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  xlab("Month")
```

where *duration* is an integer which is the number of months since the first month in the data set. So for example a house with duration 24 is in the 24th month in the dataset and corresponds to Feb 2014. Note that 24 is actually the first month in this data set, since I have filtered for duration>24.

I want the tick mark labels on the x-axis to read: 2014,2015,2016,2017,2018

However when I try:

```
+ scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("30","40","50","60","70"),
        labels=c("2014", "2015", "2016","2017","2018"))
```

The x-axis ticks simply disappear.

[image: im]

Comment: Have you tried `+ scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(30, 70, 10), labels=2014:2018))`?

Comment: I had tried continuous but had not used the seq(), and this does make it work. Thank you!

Comment: @Macter Glad it worked. But I don't think `seq` made it work, but the numeric vector `seq` returns. In your example, you passed a character vector to the `breaks` argument.